# How to enable/disable input field after selecting an option list item with EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js

I'm a beginner with EmberJS and i'm having some trouble when trying to enable/disable an input text field after selecting an option in another field.

My problem is, i have three different models: employee, bank details & banks. And i'm making a form to employee model with a select option list containing a bank list, and after selecting a bank option, the fields relatives to bank details model must be enable to input(agency & account number).

The question is, how can i enable/disable dynamically the input text field, putting it to enable or disable after the user select an option in the bank list?

Here's my code:

Employee Model:

```
App.Employee = DS.Model.extend({
  attr fields(),
  bank_detail: belongsTo('bank_detail')
});
```

Bank Model:

```
App.Bank = DS.Model.extend({
  number:  attr(),
  name:    attr(),   
  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('number') + ' - ' + this.get('name');
  }.property('number', 'name'),
  bank_details:  hasMany('bank_detail')
});
```

Bank Detail Model:

```
App.BankDetail = DS.Model.extend({
  agency:           attr(),
  agency_dv:        attr(),
  account_number:   attr(),
  account_dv:       attr(),
  employee_id:  belongsTo('employee'),
  bank:         belongsTo('bank')
});
```

====================================================================

Employee controller:

```
App.EmployeesFormController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  bankList: function() {
    return this.get('store').find('bank');
  }.property(),      
  hasBank: function() {
    return this.get('bank_id') != null;
  }.property(),  
  actions: {
    save: function(employee) {
      employee
        .save()
        .then(this.get('success').bind(this))
        .catch(this.get('fail').bind(this));
    }
  }
});
```

========================================================

Employee template / form group:

```
{{#form-group label="<%= I18n.t('active_record.models.bank') %>"
              for="employee-bank"}}
  {{view Ember.Select id="employee-bank"
                      content=bankList
                      optionValuePath="content.id"
                      optionLabelPath="content.fullName"
                      prompt="Select a bank name..."
                      selection=bank}}
{{/form-group}}
{{#form-group label="<%= I18n.t('active_record.attributes.employee.bank_details.agency') %>"
              for="employee-bank-detail-agency"}}
  {{#if hasBank}}
    {{input value=bank_detail.agency disabled=false id="employee-bank-detail-agency"}}
  {{#else}}
    {{input value=bank_detail.agency disabled=true id="employee-bank-detail-agency"}}
  {{/if}}
{{/form-group}}
{{#form-group label="<%= I18n.t('active_record.attributes.employee.bank_details.account_number') %>"
              for="employee-bank-detail-account"}}
  {{#if hasBank}}
    {{input value=bank_detail.account_number disabled=false id="employee-bank-detail-account-number"}}
  {{#else}}
    {{input value=bank_detail.account_number disabled=true id="employee-bank-detail-account-number"}}
  {{/if}}
{{/form-group}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set disabled binding for input in templates or through views. For example:

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=isChecked}}
{{input type="text" disabled=isChecked}}
```

Demo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qegequsazepe/1/